# Replacing Derived Table With Newly Created Table From Database in BO

Tags: business-objects

I have created a derived table in data foundation layer (a table defined with sql statement).
Now, I have decided that it would be a good idea to materialize that derived table, and I would like to create one in the database.
The question is - is it possible to replace derived table with the newly created table from database WITHOUT having to define all connections to other tables again?

If yes, please explan how.

Thx!
A.

(I am unsing IDT 4.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, and it's quite simple too. Just right-click the derived table that you created and select *Replace By > Database Table* from the context menu.

[image]

Comment: it is actually not functioning as I expected because when I do that it responds by making an alias table. Moreover, it does not make an alias table with the new attributes (because that is the reason I am trying to replace/update it), but it makes an alias table with the attributes that already existed in the old table. I got to say... the more I am working with this tool the less I like it. In my opinion it is copletely unintuitive and buggy software, which is unimaginable since it is owned by a large and renowned corporation and since it is on the market for a very long time. Dissapoining...

Comment: Do you happen to have the table already in your data foundation (before trying to replace it)? If so, it's completely normal that you would get an alias instead of the actual table, as you can have only one instance of the table in your DF.

Comment: Please explain why is that normal. The thing is - there is a table in my data foundation layer. The reason I am trying to replace it is because new attributes are added to the table. Why is this utterly simple action like a rocket science task in BO?

Comment: Furthermore, I have replaced the original database table with an alias table. Now if I delete the original table, the alias is deleted as well. Another rocket science try in BO would be - how to replace the new alias table with the database table? Do you have any idea Kristof?

Comment: I think I even did it somehow by using Merged table as a middleman. Don't know how anyone can work with this tool... terrible...

Comment: I need your help with Aggregate Navigation definition, please. I can't find any good example on how to use this functionality. I already posted a question. Did you see it by any chance?

Comment: @Adam, no offence, but I really think you should revisit the basics of semantic layer design. There are some specifics to designing a universe where it differs from just replicating the data model. Personally, I think that taking a step back and studying the basics again would really help resolve a lot of your frustrations. I'm not implying that IDT is perfect or without bugs, but it is actually a quite powerful abstraction layer once you understands it particularities. Have a look at [Universe Design with SAP BusinessObjects BI](http://bit.ly/1nrbpFZ) for example.

Comment: no offence taken. However, I disagree with you when it comes to BO. It is true that I am no expert. But this allegendly one of the bst BO tool is completely non-intuitive, super-slow, and some basic activities are like rocket science in BO. I already gave few examples, such as replacing a table, and now I have also noticed that when I delete a table from foundation layer and try to add the same one, BO does not allow that. It does not recognize that the tables are deleted. When I add them, it does not show them in the data foundation layer (yes - i have previously saved it).

Comment: Yes, after of years of looking at this tool, one might become an expert. However, a tool that is marketing itself as one of the best BO tool, fails at the critical points I have previously mentioned. I firmly believe that the main goal of not just BO but any tool is to simplify the end-user its utilisation and try to adapt to the user's needs as much as possible. Not the other way around.